# Islam has become a difficulty for me . Praying is difficult.Taking wudhu is difficult. Urinating is difficult . Life is bitter. What should i do?

Tags: wudu

Even going to the toilet is a difficulty. Every time after urinating some drops come out. However Not all of the drops come out . After I get out of the toilet and walk around ( 5 to 10 mins later )  I feel a few drops coming put . I use a tissue to absorb the drops and wipe the tip of the pens 3 times with the tissue. Recently these drops are coming randomly sometimes 15 to 30 minuts after urinating. I tried istibra but no success.

Because of these drops my salat  is broken when I go to sujood. Basically these drops come out whenever I exert pressure on my urethra  ( ideally when I sit down or bend down or go down in sujood  ) They don't come always and keep coming randomly.  BTW Because of this my wudhu / salat gets broken often and salah has become a tension instead of a source of peace. I am dreading the moment the next azan will be sounded even if it is 1 hour away because I will always be having these dripping problem.

Another problem is that I have a gas issue, the problem is its not possible for me to shut my anus so gas is being released continually. I release gas randomly time to time in small quantities. Whenever I try to shut my anus and hold in the gas I get nervous and a large amount of gas builds up in my rectum which ends being released during sujood ideally.

Because of this life is very difficult and bitter. Islam is supposed to be easy and indeed it used to be before I got these problems recently.

I am having a lot of tension. I am spiritually,  mentally and physically exhausted.  I am only 16 yr old and my time is being wasted on this ( around 4 hours a day wasted trying to take wudhu , trying to pray, using a tissue to wipe up the drops and sprinkling water on my clothes etc...) .I have lots of other things to do for which I have no time .

I read about the madhur ruling and I wonder if I am a madhur ?

What are the solutions to these problems  ?

Don't tell me what to do. Tell me how to do it.

Jazakallahu Khair

Comment: Whenever these drops come in your salah and gas comes in your salah your salah is still valid ,your salah is not broken by these things , you need not to do wudu again, please watch this- https://youtu.be/ra0kBiBYiFQ

Answer (score 0):

As you have a chronic illness your wudu will be valid if any drops leak after you have performed wudu. You can read fard and nafl and read Quran however the wudu must be renewed at the start of the next prayer.

• “The ruling with regards to a Ma’dhur is that he/she must perform ablution for each Salat time, and with that Wudu, one may carry out all the various prayers and worships. When the time of the prayer exits, Wudu will be nullified and it will be necessary to renew the Wudu”. (al-Lubab fi Sharh al-Kitab, 1/64).

Comment: This link explains in depth about Madhur and the rulings, however I’m not sure it is the same for each school of thought so please correct me if I’m wrong. 
https://www.ilmgate.org/rules-related-to-an-excused-person-madhur/